# sudoers.d: Allow user to not need password for sftp only

Tags: sudo, sftp

In WinSCP, I want to be able to have sudo access. In WinSCP, Advanced > SFTP > SFTP Server: `sudo su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

In Ubuntu 22.04.1:

```
echo "user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee "/etc/sudoers.d/user1-user"
```

I successfully have sudo access in WinSCP.

But I don't want to permit no password for everything. Just sftp-server. So I changed `ALL` to `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

In WinSCP, I get the error:

> Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?

Why? Is this a problem with my syntax in Ubuntu? Or a problem with WinSCP or my settings within WinSCP?

sftp-server is found in `/usr/lib/openssh/`

Comment: Try `user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

Comment: pasman pasmański, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had previously tried `user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` but it didn't work. Of course it didn't work. I forgot that I need the full path for su which is `/usr/bin/su`. Thanks pasman pasmański!

The correct way of restricting passwordless sudo for sftp is the following:

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/su -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```